# Whats a good name for a base class for Movie and Episode?

Tags: language-agnostic, refactoring

I've been refactoring Media Browser and have started to define a proper inheritance model for our domain objects

so I have

```
BaseItem
-> Video
--> <Need a name for this>
---> Episode
---> Movie
-> Folder
--> Season
```

Essentially tv show episodes and movies have some attributes in common (like actor or director listings) so I need a name for this common base class.

I don't want to chuck this in the Video base class, cause thing like mpegs that you record on your camera have no actors or directors so they are simply Videos ...

Any help with a name would be much appreciated..

Comment: It will help a lot to say the methods/properties common to Movies and Episodes (you allude to 'actor', but 'specifying all those things you intend to model' will help you or us answer the question).

Comment: Well my current tangled up domain model has: writers, actors, directors and perhaps genres in common between movies and tv episodes

Comment: I wouldn't use classes for episode vs movie, just differentiate based on some properties.

Comment: @Michael, im kind of on the DDD bandwagon at the moment, my users perceive movies and episodes as different things and I want my code to reflect that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in plain English, I've always just called them shows. "Going to see a show at the theater." "Did you catch that show on the History channel?"

Comment: Another great name, now I have to decide between Show and Production I'm leaning towards show.

Answer (score 4):

Production?

Answer (score 2):

I am fairly sure that the TV/cable industry has a term for this since scheduling a channel's lineup for a particular day involves scheduling these X's (feature movies and show episodes). I'm not sure what the term is in English though. I thought it was a program or broadcast, but I think it is more general.

Comment: Broadcast is a good candidate ... Program may be a bit too confusing for programmers ..

Answer (score 1):

I definitely agree with @Richard but I would suggest you skip the extra level "Video" and replace it with "Shows"... If the main aspect is to keep it user-friendly.

However, I think the main problem is that you are mixing up **folder structure** (user interface structure) and **class inheritance** (internal structure).

If it was for the code only you could have something like (example only, the terms may are just made up):

```
Media (ICollectionItem)
    Video
        Film
        Program
    Sound
        Sample
        Recording

Collection (ICollection)
```

But you could still show it to the user as:

```
Shows [Collection]
    Film [Film]
    Series [Collection]
        Episode [Program]
Music [Collection]
    Recordings [Collection]
        CDS [Recording]
        Vinyls [Recording]
    Sample Compilations [Collection]
        Sample [Sample]
```

Comment: Actually things like Season and Folders have some things in common with Videos in my domain model. All three have a bunch of images associated with each entity (primary/secondary/banner and backdrops) My collections are not pure collections, they have metadata associated with them

Comment: It may make sense to inject a Media between my base class and Video to allow for Music later down the line ...

Answer (score 1):

Coming from the television industry the common terminology is usually:

- Broadcaster (YTV, Teletoon, etc.)

  - Series (Ben 10, Total Drama Island, etc.)

    - Episode (1:Pilot, 2:The Biggest Mistake, 3:Overboard, etc.)

      - Character

        - Actor (who played or voiced the character)
      - Director
      - etc.

The way I see it, its not such a big deal storing your actors inside the episodes since you can always consolidate them using a method or property on Series to get all the actors.  For example:

```
allActorsInSeries = Series.Actors;
```

This format can still be applied to feature films since the episodes simply represent the film and its sequels.

Answer (score 0):

Episode and Movie have professional production in common, as opposed to your outside case of personally-produced video.  How about ReleaseVideo or CommercialVideo?

Comment: CommercialVideo can easily be confused with plain old commercial. ReleaseVideo kind of doesn't really roll of tongue

Answer (score 0):

MediaItem?

Maybe even swap MediaItem and Video so you can extend it to audio?

Answer (score 0):

What comes to mind:

- Distribution (this would allow you to have Professional and Amature too)
- Broadcast (not really, but might get you some other thoughts)